# OrderedTest returns another directory than the TestMethod

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I have `TestMethod` in my unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestLast()
{
    var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase ;
    Console.WriteLine(path);

}
```

I have inserted this `TestMethod` in an orderedTest file: `OrderedTest1.orderedtest`
I want to get the directory when the test is run. When I check the `path` variable in the method when running the `TestLast` directly in Visual Studio, I get the path of the `Debug` folder (as I am debugging):

```
C:\Users\dada\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestTest\UnitTestProject2\bin\Debug
```

But when I run the OrderedTest1.orderedtest in Debug mode in Visual Studio, I get a different value for `path` variable:

```
C:\Users\dada\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestTest\TestResults\dada_MyMachineName 2020-03-05 17_12_14\Out
```

Why is this like this and how can get the path of the `Debug` folder when debugging the orderedTest (without manually chaning the path)?

Comment: Try using TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory;

Comment: `TestContext` contains no property and the following error message is shown:`'TestContext' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentContext'`

Comment: Ah - apologies, i thought you were using nunit.